Unable to Stream Video from Camera Module in FastAPI
I'm working on a project where I need to stream video from a camera module to a web browser using FastAPI. I've implemented a function receive_frames() to receive frames from the camera module and then attempted to stream these frames using FastAPI's StreamingResponse. However, I'm encountering difficulties in getting the video to stream successfully. Here's my code:
def receive_frames():
    stream = requests.get(server_address, stream=True)
    bytes_received = bytes()
    for chunk in stream.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        bytes_received += chunk
        a = bytes_received.find(b'\xff\xd8') # JPEG start marker
        b = bytes_received.find(b'\xff\xd9') # JPEG end marker
        if a != -1 and b != -1:
            jpg = bytes_received[a:b+2]
            bytes_received = bytes_received[b+2:]
            frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

receive_frames is working fine, because my friend can use this same function for cv2 manipulation.
import os
from fastapi import APIRouter
import requests
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

from model_data.improved_detector import receive_frames, server_address

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/od",
    tags=["od"],
)

@router.get("/")
async def video():
    return StreamingResponse(receive_frames(), media_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

In this code, receive_frames() is supposed to receive JPEG frames from the camera module and video() is supposed to stream these frames to the next js application . However, the video doesn't seem to stream properly in browser or not in postman viewing network see pending request.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!
My goal is to get video stream to the nnextjs whatever our camera module is throwing.
